# Advice on Oracle Flashback Data Archive

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for some help / advice on using Flashback Data Archive.

In a test system we enabled FDA on a handful of tables.  Before enabling FDA, our UNDO tablespaces were empty - 0 MB.

After enabling FDA we ran a few tests and the UNDO tablespace usage increased to 200-300 MB.  Fair enough.

After running these tests, we left the instance alone for ~4 weeks, where there was very limited activity in the test system.

After the 4 week period, the tablespace usages increased to ~10 GB each.  We have 5 UNDO tablespaces, so total disk consumed is ~50 GB.

I dont understand why they disk usage is growing so quickly while there is little to no activity in the system.  With this kind of growth, we would need to allocate TBs of disk to support FDA in production.

Is this normal / expected behavior?  I posed this question to Oracle support and did not get much in the way of useful feedback.

Can anyone out there with experience using Flashback Data Archive confirm this growth is / is not normal behavior, and offer suggestion on configuration or otherwise?

So far it seems the solution is to allocate a whole bunch of disk to the archive process.

With the rate that it is consuming disk, we will not be able to use FDA in production.  We had enabled FDA in production in the past on 1 table - within a week it completely filled up all the UNDO tablesapces (150 GB total) and crashed the system.

If you have successfully implemented FDA, how have you handled the UNDO tablespace consumption?

Comment: FDA uses its own tablespace and should not cause growth of the undo tablespace(s). You either encountered a bug (Bug 20068538) or configured FDA incorrectly (Note 2079345.1) or it could be something else. That is all I can say due to the vague amount of information you provided.

Comment: Thanks Balazs - Are you able to provide a sample of creating the archive that does not use UNDO?  Though I assume the disk consumption will be the same, just in a different tablespace.  How can we calculate/estimate how much disk will be used by FDA?  I read something about creating the archive using compression.  Does this help?